# What material is Thor's hammer made of?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, composition, mjolnir

What is the element used to make the Hammer of Thor?

Comment: *Thor*ium... ;)

Comment: It is made out of Nokias (;

Comment: We so far have answers based on Thor from: [Norse mythology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor), [Marvel comics/movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(Marvel_Comics)), and [Stargate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(Stargate)#Thor).  What Thor are you asking about?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Mjölnir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mjolnir_%28comics%29) is made out of an Asgardian metal named 'uru'

Comment: And, its not the building material which makes it deadly... It could have been made up of light plastic. Its enchantments which make it deadly.

Answer (score 24):

And assuming you're referring to the nordic Thor instead of the Marvel Thor: Mjölnir could either be a stone hammer (Based on the name), or made from iron when Sindri and Brokkr had a bet with Loki that they could create items more beautiful than those of the Sons of Ivaldi.

The last item they created - Sindri puts iron into the forge, and whilst Brokkr is working on it Loki succeeded in distracting him (By biting his eyelid as a fly and drawing blood). This is why Mjölnir has a short handle.

> Then Sindri laid iron in the hearth and bade him blow, saying that it
>   would be spoiled if the blast failed. Straightway the fly settled
>   between Brokkr's eyes and stung his eyelid, but when the blood fell
>   into his eyes so that he could not see, then he clutched at it with
>   his hand as swiftly as he could,--while the bellows grew flat,--and he
>   swept the fly from him. Then the smith came thither and said that it
>   had come near to spoiling all that was in the hearth. Then he took
>   from the forge a hammer, put all the precious works into the hands of
>   Brokkr his brother, and bade him go with them to Ásgard and claim the
>   wager.

From the [Skáldskaparmál](http://www.germanicmythology.com/ProseEdda/BRODEURSkaldskaparmal.html).

Comment: Potatismjöl or rågmjöl? ;)

Answer (score 18):

Thor's hammer, Mjolnir is made of the fictional metal [Uru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uru_%28comics%29#Background).  [Uru's](http://marvel.wikia.com/Uru) main property is that it is a metal that holds magical enchantments well.  The ore is unique to the realm of Asgard.

Answer (score 7):

Another version of Thor's hammer is actually made of few devices and different materials, as presented in stargate SG1. From [Stargate Wiki](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Thor%27s_Hammer):

> Thor's Hammer was an Asgard device that protected the people of Cimmeria from Goa'uld interference. According to legend, the Hammer was said to be a great weapon, wielded by the god Thor. In reality, the Hammer was a complicated collection of devices, consisting of several parts, serving as Cimmeria's only line of defense.

Comment: Well basically it was a "Goa'uld plus host only" teleporter to a cave...

Answer (score 1):

Two part answer:

1) Uru...but what is Uru?

2) In the first Thor movie, Odin, I believe, mentions that Mjolnir was forged from the heart of a dying star. We know that stars of sufficient size to create neutronium at their cores do so during the last phase before death; just prior to supernova. Some result in neutron stars, others exceed the Chandrasekhar limit and become black holes.

Ergo, Uru=neutronium.

Comment: Is neutronium a stable element?

Comment: The [quote](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html) was "...forged *in* the heart..." not "...forged *from* the heart..." Big difference. ;)